# React front end on kubernetes pod fails to communicate with other serviced pod, despite networking working pod to pod

Tags: kubernetes

My kubernetes deployed react front end is failing to connect to my api. Both are containerized applications deployed with kubectl locally with minikube, along with services, but when I navigate to my deployed (minikube) react front end, it fails to connect to the backend api.

The reason this is strange is because when I exec into the pods, I am able to *curl http://{backend-service}/* from the front end, and vice versa just fine. But the react app still somehow fails the same request.

Any advice or ideas would be appreciated!

[curl from inside pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNzSJ.png)

[kubectl frontend deployment failing backend request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THJQV.png)

Please see the following yaml files that describe the application;

backend-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: diagnosy-backend
  namespace: diagnosy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: diagnosy-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: diagnosy-backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: diagnosy-backend
          image: asia-docker.pkg.dev/multi-cloud-app-413619/gcr-asia-repo/diagnosy/api:1.0.5
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3001
          imagePullPolicy: Never
```

backend-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: diagnosy-api
  namespace: diagnosy
spec:
  selector:
    app: diagnosy-backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3001
      targetPort: 3001
  type: LoadBalancer
```

frontend-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: diagnosy-frontend
  namespace: diagnosy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: diagnosy-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: diagnosy-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: diagnosy-frontend
          image: asia-docker.pkg.dev/multi-cloud-app-413619/gcr-asia-repo/diagnosy/webapp:1.0.3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          env:
            - name: DIAGNOSY_API_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: diagnosy-configmap
                  key: backend_host
            - name: DIAGNOSY_API_PORT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: diagnosy-configmap
                  key: backend_port
```

frontend-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: diagnosy-webapp
  namespace: diagnosy
spec:
  selector:
    app: diagnosy-frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: diagnosy-configmap
  namespace: diagnosy
data:
    backend_host: diagnosy-api
    backend_port: "3001"
    database_host: mongodb-service
    database_port: "27017"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your frontend isn't using DNS from K8s. If you want it to be able to call services using their service names, you'll need to run a server and proxy those calls. Otherwise, you need to expose the services (behind a LB or Ingress, with a domain). Those requests come from the browser, not inside the cluster, so they have no access to internal DNS.

Comment: Aaah, thats makes a lot of sense. Thank you for pointing that out! Running a server and proxying those calls - can that be done with something like nginx?

Comment: Yes, Nginx, or an Express server, or whatever — as long as it's a process running in the cluster, so it has access to internal DNS. With Nginx, you could have something like `proxy_pass http://backend-service:3000`.